# How to get in openerp all objects from a class?

Tags: odoo

I need to get all objects from a class and iterate through them.
I tried this, but without any results:

```
def my_method(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    pool_obj = pooler.get_pool(cr.dbname)
    my_objects=pool_obj.get('project.myobject')
    #here i'll iterate through them...
```

How can I get in 'my_objects' variable all objects of class 'project.myobject'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to search with empty parameters to get all the ids of existing objects, like:

```
myobj = pool.get('project.myobject')
ids = myobj.search(cr, uid, [])
```

Then you can browse or read them passing an id or the list of ids.

Comment: then consider mark this as the correct answer... that's all about stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forget to import pooler.

```
from openerp import pooler
```

May it will help you.

Comment: I imported the pooler. There aren't build errors in the code I have posted. The problem is that I cannot retrieve a list with all objects from the specified class

Comment: Are you facing any error or you talk about field of "project.myobject"  class/object ?

Comment: I don't have build errors. After running the code posted above the "my_objects" variable (which i want to contain all objects from class "project.myobject") is empty.